# Python mutable NamedTuple

Tags: python, struct, python-3.6, mutable, namedtuple

I am looking for a struct like data structure I can create multiple instances from and have some type hinting without being immutable.

So I have something like this:

```
class ConnectionConfig(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    url: str
    port: int
    user: str = ""
    pwd: str = ""
    client: Any = None
```

But I would like to have it mutable. I could do it like that:

```
class ConnectionConfig():
    def __init__(self, name: str, url: str, port: int, user: str = "", pwd: str = "", client: Any = None):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.port = port
        self.user = user
        self.pwd = pwd
        self.client = client
```

But man... that is ugly :/ Are there any built-in alternatives in python? (using Python 3.6.3)

Comment: Can you use `*args` and `**kwargs`?

Comment: but then I can't use type hinting anymore right?

Comment: You could use `**kwargs` and a (`for`) loop. And you could use `eval` (or `exec`) for this one. I'm just not sure about this because every time I use eval for assigning variables it throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is quite the (only) built-in way to do it, actually:

```
class ConnectionConfig():
    def __init__(self, name: str, url: str, port: int, user: str = "",
                 pwd: str = "", client: Any = None):
        pass
```

Reading [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) I haven't found any other alternatives that fit your needs. Continuing the PEP chain, I guess this quote from [PEP 20 The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) explains it:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ConnectionConfig():
    name: str
    url: str
    port: int
    user: str = ""
    pwd: str = ""
    client: Any = None
    def __init__(self, **kv):
        self.__dict__.update(kv)
```

then you can specify everything in the constructor

```
c=ConnectionConfig(port=22)

print (c.port)  # will print 22
```

Comment: I actually already tried that one before. But the type hints are not working that way. I maybe didn't specify that in my question good enough.

Comment: The type hints will not work because they are not in the __init__

Answer (score 1):

There is a compact solution on the base of [recordclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/) library:

```
> pip3 install recordclass

from recordclass import dataobject

class ConnectionConfig(dataobject):
    name: str
    url: str
    port: int
    user: str = ""
    pwd: str = ""
    client: Any = None

>>> con = ConnectionConfig('name','url',8080,'user','secret',tcp_client)

>>> sys.getsizeof(con)
108   # PyHEAD (16) + 6*sizeof(*void) bytes
```

If one want faster instance creation there is an option:

```
class ConnectionConfig(dataobject, fast_new=True):
    name: str
    url: str
    port: int
    user: str = ""
    pwd: str = ""
    client: Any = None
```

(Note: that this one could be less comfortable with IDE editor's autocompletion)

Another option:

```
>>> from recordclass import make_dataclass
>>> ConnectionConfig = make_dataclass(
          "ConnectionConfig",
          [('name',str), ('url',str), ('port',str), 
           ('use',str), ('pwd',str), ('client',Any)],
          defaults=(None,), 
          fast_new=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using recordclass (pip install recordclass)?

```
from recordclass import recordclass


>>> Point = recordclass('Point', 'x y')

>>> p = Point(3, 2)
>>> p
Point(x=3, y=2)
>>> p.x = 8
```

It's (nearly) the same api as namedtuple and it's mutable

Comment: I would prefer sth built in. Nevertheless, I also don't see how type hinting can be used.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't work with your IDE? ipython knows to autocomplete with recordclass

Comment: I never said it does not work. But again, how can I use type hints with recordclass. As I see it, that does not work.

Comment: Jodo: `recordclass` already support typehints::

    from recordclass import RecordClass
    from typing import Any

    class ConnectionConfig(RecordClass):
        name: str
        url: str
        port: int
        user: str = ""
        pwd: str = ""
        client: Any = None

    >>> cf = ConnectionConfig('name', 'example.com', 8080, 'qwerty', None)
    >>> print(cf.name, cf.url, cf.port, cf.pwd, repr(cf.client))
    name example.com 8080 None None

Answer (score 0):

Calling "_asdict()" on creation of the NamedTuple will transform it to an OrderedDict(), but not really satisfying at all...

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class ConnectionConfig(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    url: str
    port: int
    user: str = ""
    pwd: str = ""

mutable_connection_cfg = ConnectionConfig("my_name", "my_url", 111, "my_user", "my_pwd")._asdict()

print(mutable_connection_cfg)
>> OrderedDict([('name', 'my_name'), ('url', 'my_url'), ('port', 111), ('user', 'my_user'), ('pwd', 'my_pwd')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pass` statement.

```
class myclass: pass
```

Then you can create the attributes just before using them:

```
myclass.a=0
myclass.b='string'
```

Comment: If you're going this route, a cleaner way is to use [SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html?highlight=simplenamespace#types.SimpleNamespace).